# Cannot control volume or play/pause for IE 8 embed sound

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, embed

I found some similar topic but that didn't help.

I need to play music in IE8, this code works:

```html
<object id="audio_object_ie" classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" style="display:none;"> 
        <param name="URL" value="sample.mp3" />
        <param name="uiMode" value="invisible" /> 
        <param name="autoStart" value="true" />
        <param name="volume" value="30" />
        <param name="mute" value="false" />
        <param name="playCount" value="2147483647" />
</object>
```

The parameters work OK when I edit them, but I want to change (on the fly) the value of eider play/pause or volume parameter, I tried these JavaScript lines without having any effect:

```js
document.getElementById('audio_object_ie').volume = 100;
document.getElementById('audio_object_ie').mute = false;
document.getElementById('audio_object_ie').play();
```